saving results according to conditions
I am trying to take the specific data I need from the loaded excel file,
I entered the conditions, where in the first condition it pulls out the cell, the cell where 'Entrance (number) Floor' is located, and if the condition is met, then the data is taken from the cell below, which is one cell below
# reading the Excel file
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\lubom\\python\\pythonPdf\\pokusnew_zaverecna.xlsx'
xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)

results = []

# Scrolling through all sheets in an Excel file
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    
    # Initialization of lists for individual data types

    poschodie_list = []
 
for col in df.columns:
    for row_idx in range(len(df)):
        cell = df.at[row_idx, col]
        if pd.notna(cell) and isinstance(cell, str):
            
            
            if cell.strip() == 'Vchod (číslo) Poschodie':  # A condition for processing a specific string
                if row_idx + 1 < len(df):
                    next_cell = df.at[row_idx + 1, col]
                    if pd.notna(next_cell) and isinstance(next_cell, str):
                        # Splits the string from the back and takes only the last segment after the last space
                        last_part = next_cell.rsplit(' ', 1)[-1] if ' ' in next_cell else next_cell
                        poschodie_list.append(last_part.strip())
                       # print(poschodie_list)
                    else:
                        poschodie_list.append('')  # An empty string if the next cell contains no text

            elif 'Poschodie' in cell:
                if cell.strip() == 'Poschodie':  # Control for Poschodie
                    if row_idx + 1 < len(df):
                        next_cell = df.at[row_idx + 1, col]
                        poschodie_list.append(next_cell.strip() if pd.notna(next_cell) else '')
                        #print(poschodie_list)
                    else:
                        poschodie_list.append('')
                else:
                    poschodie_list.append(cell.replace('Poschodie', '').strip())

results = []
for i in range(len(poschodie_list)):
    poschodie = poschodie_list[i] if i < len(poschodie_list) else ''
    results.append([poschodie])

columns = ['Poschodie']
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=columns)

# Uloženie výsledkov do nového Excel súboru
output_file_path = 'vysledky_zaverecna.xlsx'
results_df.to_excel(output_file_path, index=False)

print(f'Výsledky boli uložené do súboru {output_file_path}')

I save the results in a new table
The results are good, the problem is that the order does not match.
It stores my conditions individually, although they are in one column, but it stores all the results from one condition in a row and the results of the second condition below the results of the first condition.
I need the results to be saved as the file is passed.
Could someone help me solve this?

I don't understand what you're asking.  The rows and columns in your dataframe become rows and columns in your spreadsheet.   If you need things in order, then you need to add them to the correct spot inside the dataframe.  Also, your indentation is messed up, which makes it difficult to visualize the problem.
